# How to set the Expect call to check that a method is not called in Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Using Rhino Mocks, how do I ensure that a method is not called while setting up the Expectations on the mock object.

In my example, I am testing the Commit method and I need to ensure that the Rollback method is not called while doing the commit. (this is because i have logic in the commit method that will automatically rollback if commit fails)

Here's how the code looks like..

```
[Test]
public void TestCommit_DoesNotRollback() 
{
    //Arrange
    var mockStore = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IStore>();
    mockStore.Expect(x => x.Commit());
    //here i want to set an expectation that x.Rollback() should not be called.

    //Act
    subject.Commit();

    //Assert
    mockStore.VerifyAllExpectation();
}
```

Of course, I can do this at Assert phase like this:

```
mockStore.AssertWasNotCalled(x => x.Rollback());
```

But i would like to set this as an Expectation in the first place.

Comment: Curious why you want to use Expectation, and not just go for AssertWasNotCalled?

Comment: @Cousken AssertWasNotCalled() does not seem to work with BackToRecord() and Replay(), maybe that's the reason??

Answer (score 36):

Another option would be:

```
mockStore.Expect(x => x.Rollback()).Repeat.Never();
```

Answer (score 8):

Is this what are you looking for?

```
ITest test = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ITest>();
test.Expect(x => x.TestMethod()).AssertWasNotCalled(mi => {});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

```
        mockStore.Stub(x => x.DoThis()).Repeat.Times(0);

        //EXECUTION HERE 

        x.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

Answer (score 2):

For this case I created an extension method to better show my intent

```
public static IMethodOptions<RhinoMocksExtensions.VoidType> ExpectNever<T>(this T mock, Action<T> action) where T : class
{
    return mock.Expect(action).IgnoreArguments().Repeat.Never();
}
```

*Note* the IgnoreArguments() call. I'm assuming that you don't want the method to be called ever...no matter what the parameter value(s) are.